# how to open google.navigation intent inside android view or fragment

Tags: android

Is it possible to open google navigation intent inside my appln (in a view like a fragment). I would like to display other info to the user as the navigation is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the intent starts an activity which means you leave your app completely and go to the google navigation app

Comment: Okay, then how do I integrate navigation within my app. I am not able to find any Google Android APIs for navigation.

Comment: the only thing you can do is use Google Directions Api that returns you the directions to the location you want to go. then you have to do everything yourself, meaning you have to plot the route on the map, handle the voice navigation etc.. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/